# Drag and Drop functionality for multiple images

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, android-imageview

I was wondering if there's any tutorial having a drag and drop functionality on differing images making them target specific?

By this I mean, If you have say, 4 draggable images; `image_drag_1`, `image_drag_2`, `image_drag_3`, and `image_drag_4` and 4 drop_target images; `image_drop_1`, `image_drop_2`, `image_drop_3` and `image_drop_4`.

`image_drag_1` should be matched to image_drop_1 and any attempt to drop `image_drag_1` on any other drop image or location in the screen layout, makes `image_drag_1` snap back to its original position.

[This tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implementing-drag-and-drop-functionality/)  implements a drag drop functionality for textview, though not target specify.

I have tried on my own implementing my own drag and drop following the tutorual stated above, leaving textview to be draggable and the imageviews, the drop targets. It just crashes my emulator.

Below can be found my .java file:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.graphics.Typeface;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //Imageview to drag the image is dragged into
    private ImageView image1, image2;

    //textview the image is dragged into
    private TextView choice1, choice2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //views to drag
        image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        //views to drop onto
        choice1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.choice_1);
        choice2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.choice_2);

        //set touch listeners
        image1.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
        image2.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());

        //set drag listeners
        choice1.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
        choice2.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());

    }

    private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                /*
                 * Drag details: we only need default behavior
                 * - clip data could be set to pass data as part of drag
                 * - shadow can be tailored
                 */
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                //start dragging the item touched
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } 

    /**
     * DragListener will handle dragged views being dropped on the drop area
     * - only the drop action will have processing added to it as we are not
     * - amending the default behavior for other parts of the drag process
     *
     */
    private class ChoiceDragListener implements OnDragListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                //no action necessary
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                //no action necessary
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:        
                //no action necessary
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                //handle the dragged view being dropped over a drop view
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

                //stop displaying the view where it was before it was dragged
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                //view dragged item is being dropped on
                TextView dropTarget = (TextView) v;

                //view being dragged and dropped
                ImageView dropped = (ImageView) view;

                //update the text in the target view to reflect the data being dropped
                dropTarget.setText(dropped.getImageAlpha());

                //make it bold to highlight the fact that an item has been dropped
                dropTarget.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

                //if an item has already been dropped here, there will be a tag
                Object tag = dropTarget.getTag();

                //if there is already an item here, set it back visible in its original place
                if(tag!=null)
                {
                    //the tag is the view id already dropped here
                    int existingID = (Integer)tag;
                    //set the original view visible again
                    findViewById(existingID).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                //set the tag in the target view being dropped on - to the ID of the view being dropped
                dropTarget.setTag(dropped.getId());
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                //no action necessary
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    } 
}
```

My xml file is as below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingRight="50dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/choice_1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:background="@drawable/choice"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/choice_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/choice_2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:background="@drawable/choice"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/choice_2" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_desc"
    android:src="@drawable/firefighter" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_desc"
    android:src="@drawable/clown" />
```

Any advise as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you discussing your problem or asking logic ? this room is for discussing problems only, not to ask whole logic, please try it yourself.

Comment: HI @umesh I have edited my question above. Please see to it and kindly advise accordingly. Thanks. :-)